# How to catch email sending exceptions in Django 1.10

Tags: django, python-3.5

I am sending email messages at different places in my application.

```
msg.send(fail_silently=True)
```

helps to avoid error page from displaying to end users when there is an error while sending the email. Is it possible to catch this error so that I make a log or execute a custom function?

Note:
I am using Django 1.10.4 with Python 3.5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it says in the Django docs for `send_email` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/#send-mail):

> **fail_silently**: A boolean. If it’s False, send_mail will raise an smtplib.SMTPException. See the smtplib docs for a list of possible exceptions, all of which are subclasses of SMTPException.

So you can do:

```
from smtplib import SMTPException

try:
    msg.send()
except SMTPException as e:
    print('There was an error sending an email: ', e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Once! It will cover any type of possible errors.

```
from smtplib import SMTPException

try:
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [to_email], fail_silently=False)

except BadHeaderError:              # If mail's Subject is not properly formatted.
    print('Invalid header found.')
except SMTPException as e:          # It will catch other errors related to SMTP.
    print('There was an error sending an email.'+ e)
except:                             # It will catch All other possible errors.
    print("Mail Sending Failed!")
```